# OnEdit script to Auto-increment cells - little conflict if users tick checkbox at the same time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As an alternative to using an Arrayformula, I have the following script which basically auto-increment 
 cells within a specific column to generate a unique ID

The only problem that I'm facing, is that if 2 users tick the checkbox at the same exact time (which I've tried myself even with half second delay) it gives them the same ID, which is a problem for the next task.

Is there any trick (or alternative approach) to get around this little problem? At the moment I'm just using a conditional formatting to highlight any duplicates of Ids to help users (i.e. if a user sees the ID in red, he deletes it, then tick the checkbox again to get a new ID)

Thank you.

**SCRIPT:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var watchColumns = [1]; //when checkbox is ticked, auto-numbering will be triggered
  var autoColumn = 3;
  var headerRows = 1;
  var watchSheet = "Sheet1";

  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (e.value !== undefined && sheet.getName() == watchSheet) {
    if (watchColumns.indexOf(range.getColumn()) > -1) {
      var row = range.getRow();
      if (row > headerRows) {
        var autoCell = sheet.getRange(row, autoColumn);
        if (!autoCell.getValue()) {
          var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
          var temp = 1;
          for (var i = headerRows, length = data.length; i < length; i++)
            if (data[i][autoColumn - 1] > temp)
              temp = data[i][autoColumn - 1];
          autoCell.setValue(temp + 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`documentLock`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service#getdocumentlock) to prevent any user of the current document from concurrently running a section of code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've tried something like that `function testWait(){
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock(); lock.waitLock(50000); 
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); lock.releaseLock();
}` but without much success. any guidance?

Comment: @Nabnub See [sample script here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock)